# Fedora 22 dnf use cache only

Tags: fedora, dnf

Running on Fedora 22, any time I want to install a package, e.g.:

```
$ sudo dnf install lshw
RPM Fusion for Fedora 22 - Free - Updates                                855 kB/s | 224 kB     00:00    
RPM Fusion for Fedora 22 - Nonfree - Updates                             504 kB/s |  52 kB     00:00
...
```

dnf downloads updates from the repositories. It can be stopped by using this switch:

```
-C, --cacheonly       run entirely from system cache, don't update cache
```

Can this be made a default option somehow? I.e. I want to manually update the cache as needed via `dnf check-update` and `dnf upgrade`.

This is what I have so far:

- I tried changing options that look related to metadata / cache updates per http://dnf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/conf_ref.html - `metadata_expire=never`, `metadata_timer_sync=0`
- Disabled dnf-makecache timer (`systemctl disable dnf-makecache.service`)
- I don't have `dnf-automatic` installed

I could not find anything else that would help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Circa 2022, there is an equivalent configuration item in:

`/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`

Reference: https://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/conf_ref.html#main-options

`cacheonly: boolean
If set to True DNF will run entirely from system cache, will not update the cache and will use it even in case it is expired. Default is False.`

Exact format needed in the dnf config file is:

`cacheonly=True`

Note that this also causes `dnf install packagename` to fail as it does not try to download any rpm files that aren't already in the cache, even though the cached metadata tells it the exact file it needs to download.

Comment: Thanks for an update!